# I installed DNS server in my initial Ubuntu server installion how do I uninstall it?

Tags: server, dns

I installed a DNS server in my initiate Ubuntu server installation how do I uninstall it?
Cause I don't want it any more and I don't want it laying around cause I heard the more server services my server has the more it can be exploited or there are more ways it can be exploited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to remove the bind9 package and any other dependant packages which are no longer needed, and also purging bind9 config/data too.
run this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge bind9
```

Or similarly:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove bind9
```